# Push list of data to firebase not working

Tags: android, database, firebase, push

I am trying to use the firebase push() function, as I want to add a list off data to an allready existing list. The setValue() function overwrites existing data.

This is what I used to do:

```
 DatabaseReference childref =  mDatabase.child("users").child(uih.getUserData().getUsername()).child("answered_questions");
                        childref.setValue(getAnsweredQuestions(questionViewList));
```

This worked, but every time I use this function the data is overwritten and this is not what I want. I tried using the Push function as described by the firebase documation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data

I am not sure I am doing it right, but it is not working. And this is when I tried to implement the push() function:

```
DatabaseReference childref =  mDatabase.child("users").child(uih.getUserData().getUsername()).child("answered_questions");
                    String key = childref.push().getKey();    
                    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                    childUpdates.put( key, questionViewList);
                    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

The exception I get is:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class class scrambled.nl.generationr.QuestionView
```

And this is weird, since I did not receive this error while doing the setValue method. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong and how I should push a list to firebase?

**edit:**

What I can do is:

```
DatabaseReference childref =  mDatabase.child("users").child(uih.getUserData().getUsername()).child("answered_questions");
                            childref.push().setValue(getAnsweredQuestions(questionViewList));
```

In added the push() here. This works, but instead of just increasing my list, i add another layer in my list so I actually get an array of arrays instead of a longer list.

See here the result:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample of your database structure.  Based on the code I see it looks like for each user there is a child location called "answered_questions". Are you simply trying to add a new answered question to that users answered questions list?

Comment: That is indeed exactly what I am trying to do: each user has a list of answered_question and I want to add a List<AnsweredQuestion> (Java Object) to this list

Comment: ok...I should be able to help with that

Comment: can you post inside of `getAnsweredQuestions(questionViewList)` method or the type it returns? and what is the database structure that you expected? post it as a JSON format if possible

Answer (score 2):

**Saving a List of AnsweredQuestion objects:**

This assumes you've followed the rules when designing your `AnsweredQuestion.class` so that the Java object can be used to store data in Firebase. If you need guidance for that check under the "Basic write operations" heading for saving data in the documentation.

```
//List of AnsweredQuestions
List<AnsweredQuestion> mAllAnswers;
....

//create the database reference that points to the correct parent node
//where answeres are stored for each user    
DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("users").child(uih.getUserData().getUsername()).child("answered_questions");

//Iterate over your List of AnsweredQuestion objects and use push() along with setValue() 
//to store a single AnsweredQuestion object to a unique location in your database.
for(AnsweredQuestion answer : mAllAnswers){ 
    ref.push().setValue(answer);
}
```

**Retrieve all answered questions for a user:**

```
//create List to store AnsweredQuestion object
List<AnsweredQuestion> mAllAnswers = new ArrayList<AnsweredQuestion>();
...

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //iterate over datasnapshot to get/store each AnsweredQuestion object
            if(datSnapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   AnsweredQuestion answer = snapshot.getValue(AnsweredQuestion.class);
                   mAllAnswers.add(answer);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //handle error
        }
});
```

There are multiple ways to retrieve the answers for each user, using `.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` is just one way. You can also use a `FirebaseListAdapter` or `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` if you wanted to display the answers in a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.